# Swagger description hides endpoints in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I'm facing with a very strange behaviour in my application.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
@Validated
@Api(tags = "User controller v2")
public class UserController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get details of a user by id")
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Authorization information is missing or invalid."),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Requested resource is forbidden for current user"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")})
    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserDetails(@PathVariable @NotNull String userId) {
        // calling service methods
    }
}
```

This works good and it's how I see it on /swagger-ui.html
[image]

But if I add any swagger description to my request params like a default value, I can't see this method in the swagger anymore:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get details of a user by id")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Authorization information is missing or invalid."),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Requested resource is forbidden for current user"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")})
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserDetails(
    @ApiParam(defaultValue = "12345") @PathVariable @NotNull String userId) {
    // calling service methods
}
```

[image]

This is how my swagger configured

```
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.test"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("My test service")
            .version("2.0")
            .build();
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[] {authorizationScope};
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }
}
```

Also, in my app logs I see such message:

```
ERROR [,,,] 36927 --- [  restartedMain] s.d.s.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader  : Skipping process path[/api/v2/users/{userId}], method[getUserDetails] as it has an error.
```

Any ideas why it may happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging Spring context I found such error in the ApiDescriptionReader class:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam.allowEmptyValue()Z`

I have solved this issue by adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```